# Late answers review queue automatically jumps from 'Recommend deletion' to 'Other action'

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

I was reviewing a Late Answer and flagged it as 'Not an answer'. Now I want to complete my review as 'Recommend deletion', but when I select it and click Submit, the UI automatically selects 'Other action' (briefly visible before the canned comment dialog pops up):

[image]

This does not happen for other actions, e.g. after upvoting a post I can still choose 'Looks OK'.

Comment: I experienced the same bug earlier today.

Comment: Added to the backlog to be addressed as part of bug duty.

Comment: ... How are you seeing recommend deletion in First answers anyway? That slot should be "share feedback" not "recommend deletion" - or, at least, that's what I see?

Comment: @Catija oops ... thanks for catching that.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense! Thanks - This seems to happen whether it's "Recommend deletion" or "Delete" - can you confirm that this seems to just be an optical issue and the function (recommend deletion review) works just fine? If it's just the radial changing but not impacting review, it's likely lower priority than if it's actually hampering reviewing. (also, you can move the modal around to reveal the radial being incorrect)

Comment: @Catija it seems just optical - [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/30024222) and [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/412221) have the right status.

Comment: This is due to some lingering behavior from the V1 of this queue. I put together a fix that I think will work - once it's approved and on its way out the door I'll write up an answer with a bit more explanation. Thanks for reporting!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fixed and will be out in the next release.

Here's what happened: in the old version of Late Answers, you could only either select "I'm Done" or "No Action Needed." This meant that it made sense for the selector to automatically switch between them based on if you had taken actions or not. Now, however, you can take actions and decide to finish out the task with a different result. I had to amend the check so that it only enables and disables "Other action" without automatically selecting it. (It still deselects it if it becomes disabled.)

Thanks for reporting!

Comment: Looks like this introduced another bug: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371240/other-action-is-not-selected-automatically-anymore-in-review-queues