# 'Other action' is not selected automatically anymore in review queues

Tags: bug, status-review, review

As of today, the 'Other action' option in the First Answers, First Questions and Late Answer queues is not selected automatically anymore after performing a (qualifying) action, such as

- voting on the post
- editing the post
- flagging the post
- upvoting a comment

This used to be the case, at least earlier today, and also in the old versions of the First Posts and Late Answers queue, where a qualifying action automatically enabled the 'I'm Done' button.

Comment: Probably caused by the fix for [your earlier bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370631/377214).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog that would not surprise me :)

Comment: This was deliberate but I think the best middle ground is to auto-select "Other action" when there isn't already another option selected, and if there is, to leave the other option selected. What do you think?

Comment: @kristinalustig sounds great!

Comment: Awesome. I'm gonna get working on that ASAP, I'll update the post when it's ready to go.