# Unable to pass First Question / First Answer review audits

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, review-audits

There's something wrong with some review audit like [this First Questions one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/242109). I recognized [the question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/433259/173647) from the Hot Network Questions (and the 6k views is also a giveaway - interesting that it isn't rounded!), so I clicked the upvote button. Normally, that would immediately make me pass the audit. Now, only the 'Other action' option becomes available and upon clicking that, [you fail the audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/30293284).

I don't see any JavaScript errors in the console, and this happens both in the latest Firefox and Safari on macOS 11.6.1.

[Here](https://i.imgur.com/P6ov4rB.mp4) is a screencast.

Also reported on Meta Stack Overflow: [I didn't pass when I downvoted a deleted answer that had negative score?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412941/4751173)

Comment: Thanks for reporting. I'm looking into this right now. This is probably related to a recent change I just got out. *Edit*: I was mistaken, this is not related to my change (and fix linked below).

Comment: Looks like I jumped to conclusions too quickly on this one - my linked fix is unrelated to your issue outlined here, your report just came in at the same time as I was seeing the other issue. I can't confirm whether this is an intentional change, I _do_ see the _"Other action"_ part being enabled after your upvote. Would that pass the audit properly?

Comment: @HamVocke I can try, but that would destroy the example. I'm not sure it's reproducible yet. I *am* glad you fixed the other bug, that one was way more important :)

Comment: @HamVocke no, that doesn't pass the audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/30293284 (don't worry about the failed audit, but this is the last time I'm going to do that experiment :P)

Comment: @HamVocke I've just failed [this SO First Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/30295590) audit. I knew it was an audit as I was looking at the question and the answer wasn't there. Downvoting didn't trigger the audit response as before, so I selected other action, only to be told I'd failed the audit and was now review-banned. If up/down-voting is, alone, no longer sufficient to pass an audit it'd be nice if that was made clearer.

Comment: @HamVocke it might be related to earlier bug reports of mine: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371240/295232 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370631/295232.

Comment: @DavidBuck Downvoting and then "Share Feedback" will pass the audit (though the downvote is unnecessary if you know it's an audit). Hopefully, raising a flag will also pass, but I haven't tested that.

Comment: @AdrianMole Good to know - but until yesterday, downvoting alone was enough to pass an audit. Today, it's not and I'm in review-prison as a result...

Comment: Oh, shoot me. I've just failed another audit for the same reasons as the OP and got a second ban - now for upvoting a good question. "We suspect that you are not actually reviewing the tasks." is a pretty unpleasant reaction for being banned for upvoting a good question. Why do you need to upvote AND click looks OK? Surely upvoting should implicitly be looks OK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I just posted on [this report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412941/i-didnt-pass-when-i-downvoted-a-deleted-answer-that-had-negative-score/415115#415115) (but copying here for posterity):

This should be fixed now. Audits broke on November 8 on the First Question and First Answer queues when a deliberate switch fall-through in the typescript ... un-fell-through?... and a critical part of the audit code was no longer being correctly referenced. I fixed this in December and fully forgot to also update Meta about it, my apologies. You should now be able to pass audits in the correct scenarios. Please let me know if you're still experiencing this issue, and thanks for the report!

Comment: this is why one [does not use fallthrough](https://stackoverflow.com/q/188461/11407695) switches :) Joking aside, thanks for fixing this (I assume the `no-fallthrough` rule is now enabled in the liner?)