# Help center page on flairs links to a YouTube video that has since been made private

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, flair, link-rot

Article in question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/flair

> Flair is an image summarizing your accomplishments (your reputation,
> your badges, the top sites you've participated on), suitable for
> display on your own website or printing out and pinning to a vest [if
> that's what you prefer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJtrLKGZZFg).

That [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJtrLKGZZFg) is private. Is this supposed to imply that *somebody's vest* is private? Remove it and [replace it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371702/why-is-the-flair-pages-vest-pinning-youtube-video-private?noredirect=1#comment1241635_371702)  with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7SNEdjftno), which is the same video, but a live version (confirmed by [Wayback Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayback_Machine)).

Comment: Classic link rot. Posting external links is always a risk, that the linked content will be removed. With images the solution is to host on SE imgur domain, with videos there's no way to prevent the rot, but need someone to be able to edit. Hopefully a CM can do it.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 interestingly Glorfindel posted [a screencast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371701) today hosted on imgur. Maybe it is possible to host videos there?

Comment: @bad_coder only [up to 60 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEZsX.png).

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 I guess an animated GIF is still the better choice...

Comment: @bad_coder if possible, yeah, sure.

Comment: @VScode_fanboy yeah, the actual result is exactly the same: the people who visit the page can't see the content.

Comment: These two videos would be better, and less rude: https://youtu.be/Zo1XwaXF86k   https://youtu.be/XN4bUXEC7AQ

Comment: The reference here on Stack Exchange is most likely to [Office Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Space) though Atwood never revealed it (as far as I know). There are other less egregious scenes from it involving flair, e.g. [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ChQK8j6so8) (*"express yourself"*).

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum: It was definitely an Office Space reference – see the script link and extended quote in the original SO blog post that announced the flair feature: [Now Earn Valuable Flair!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/15/nowearn-valuable-flair/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The link has been removed, so I'm marking this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

From reading the comments here, I can understand that having a link to a video that includes someone flicking off their boss... may not really be particularly appropriate. I think that it's fun (even though [we hate fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)) and if this were a FAQ or other meta post instead of our Help Center article, I'd probably choose differently but since these pages are our official documentation of features, we decided that removing the video was the better call here.

Comment: That... doesn't really come into play here? The video that was linked to was the same one that had been there previously, just a version that was still available. I don't think that I indicate you as the source in my answer.