# Round number of views in review queues

Tags: feature-request, review, views

If the number of views on a question is 1,000 or higher, it's rounded to the nearest 1k (and you can see the exact amount when hovering over it). The review queues form an exception; while those questions are less likely to need review, it happens from time to time, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/30289932). Could those view counts be rounded too, for consistency?

[image]

Additional benefit: they make (positive) review audits [a little bit more difficult to spot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371701/295232).