# 500 Internal Server Error in review queues

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, 500-server-error

The review items

- https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/close/112071
- https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/112082
- https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/114803

say:

> An error occurred when loading the review item. Please try again.

The Network console shows this HTTP error:

> POST https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/next-task/112082 [HTTP/2 500 Internal Server Error 370ms]

---

Update: It seems that weird server error is gone and we are back to normal.

Comment: Yup. It's the same issue that's causing [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371701/review-audit-not-passed-after-upvoting). I just got a change out that introduced this bug. A fix is going out as I'm writing this. Sorry about the hassle.

Comment: @HamVocke Anything I can do? Inspect tabbing is available - what data do you need?.

Comment: @VScode_fanboy buy him coffee... ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 hugh!

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412934/1364007) on Meta Stack Overflow. Suggested edits seems less susceptible for some reason.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Seems the error is spreading fast

Comment: @Ham I was thinkng of providing all of the stack straces and stuff to you that time. What caused this bug?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This one's on me. I pushed a small change to review queues this morning that introduced an error when rendering review items in the queue.

I just deployed a fix and we should be back to normal.

The fix was trivial but it took a while to build out, so review queues across the Stack Exchange network have been affected for about 37 minutes, from *2021-11-09 09:00 UTC* until *2021-11-09 09:37 UTC*.

Sorry for the inconvenience, folks. Proper caffeination would've helped this morning.

Comment: Proper caffeination - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371705/bug-on-review-queues#comment1241642_371705?

Comment: Coming right up ☕

Comment: @bad_coder good emoli, also, it seems this has been spread everywhere?

Comment: You need one of [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AegCb.png). ;)

Comment: @Shadow you have restored my faith in normal smiling content.

Comment: @Shadow https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371705/bug-on-review-queues#comment1241649_371707