# Diff doesn't take stripped HTML tags into account

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, revisions-list, diff

Yesterday I edited [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/571/23377) to correct the display of something in angle brackets, `<root_music_folder>`. The Markdown parser thinks it's an HTML tag, it's not on the [allow list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/295232) so it strips it out. There are a couple of ways to fix it, but the one I chose here (`&lt;root_music_folder&gt;`) is not picked up correctly by the diff, which can been both in the [revision list](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/571/revisions) and the [review queue item](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/62751) (you might have to click the 'Inline' or the 'Side-by-side' button first).

[image]

The Markdown diff works:

[image]

Comment: **Side Note:** The optimal way to fix it would be using the CommonMark escape character `\<tag_text\>` instead of the HTML escape characters `&lt;` `&gt;` because it's easier to read and avoids mixing HTML with CommonMark.

Comment: The problem is not that it's ignoring anything. The revision history is always rendered on the spot with the latest version of the renderer. And for whatever reason, the server-side renderer is escaping those angled brackets in every revision back through the original when running it. The diff isn't catching it because technically, post-render, you didn't actually change anything. Though I'm not sure when it started escaping things or under what circumstances it chooses to. If it was still stripping it as an invalid tag, it wouldn't appear at all in old revisions.

Comment: @Marijn Glorfindel, What happened, looks like another case of [no proper caffeination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371705/500-internal-server-error-in-review-queues#comment1241651_371707)

Comment: @Marijn it's early here - one cup of coffee can make a lot of *diff*erence ... thanks!